# Get-EventLog -Log "Microsoft-Windows-Ntfs/Operational" fails with "does not exist"

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-event-log

I am making a script that pulls all non-empty logs and saves them as either evtx, csv, or xml. I have got the script working for the base logs (application, security, system, etc.), and those that have spaces. However, I keep getting errors with any that have forward slashes (`/`) in them (e.g. `Microsoft-Windows-Ntfs/Operational`). I tried swapping the `/` out with dash, spaces, abbreviated, and underscores: they all result in the error below.

***Note:*** I am am using `-newest 20` in the code for testing, to ease the load and save time.

Example of Code (Get the same results with either):

`get-eventlog -log "Microsoft-Windows-Ntfs/Operational" -newest 20`

OR

```
$Logname = "Microsoft-Windows-Ntfs/Operational"
get-eventlog -log $logname -newest 20`
```

ERROR:

```
get-eventlog : The event log 'Microsoft-Windows-Ntfs/Operational' on computer '.' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-eventlog -log "Microsoft-Windows-Ntfs/Operational" -newest 20
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-EventLog], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetEventLogCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Get-EventLog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-eventlog) only sees this

```
> get-eventlog -List

  Max(K) Retain OverflowAction        Entries Log
  ------ ------ --------------        ------- ---
  20’480      0 OverwriteAsNeeded      18’888 Application
  20’480      0 OverwriteAsNeeded           0 HardwareEvents
     512      7 OverwriteOlder              0 Internet Explorer
  20’480      0 OverwriteAsNeeded           0 Key Management Service
  15’360      0 OverwriteAsNeeded      19’094 Operations Manager
                                              Security
   8’192      0 OverwriteAsNeeded       7’012 Symantec Endpoint Protection Client
  20’480      0 OverwriteAsNeeded     102’800 System
  15’360      0 OverwriteAsNeeded      14’144 Windows PowerShell
```

In addition, the documentation also states

> `Get-EventLog` uses a Win32 API that is deprecated. The results may not be accurate. Use the `Get-WinEvent?  cmdlet instead.

Thus use [Get-WinEvent](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent), which works fine:

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName "Microsoft-Windows-Ntfs/Operational"


   ProviderName: Microsoft-Windows-Ntfs

TimeCreated                     Id LevelDisplayName Message
-----------                     -- ---------------- -------
21.06.2021 01:24:48            142 Information      Summary of disk space usage, since last event:...
21.06.2021 01:24:38            142 Information      Summary of disk space usage, since last event:...
21.06.2021 01:24:38            142 Information      Summary of disk space usage, since last event:...
20.06.2021 01:24:44            142 Information      Summary of disk space usage, since last event:...
```

Comment: Swapping Get-EventLog >>FOR>> Get-WinEvent seemed to fix the issue. Thank you!